# Excel 2007: Unhelpful error message if VBA is not installed

Tags: microsoft-excel

My application generates macro-enabled Excel 2007 workbooks (.xlsm files).

When a user who did not install VBA as part of their office installation opens such a workbook, they see an error message like this:

[image: Excel error dialog]

Is there any way to trigger a more helpful error message which actually explains the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can handle this error as it'd have to read your VBA to know what to do.